# User is not getting created in Firebase web app

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

User is not getting created ! The same code works on another sample file I got from youtube , but when I copied and used in my code , it is not working. The user is successfully created in my database with my init-details on that sample file,so I dont think the problem is with my firebase , its somewhere here i think.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if(user != null){

    }

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.

  }
});

function login(){

  var userEmail = document.getElementById("ie").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("ip").value;

    window.alert(userEmail+ " "+ userPass);
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });

}

function logout(){
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```

---

```
  <html>
        <head>
        <title>Admin Login</title>
            <link href="index-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>    
        </head>
        <body>
         <div class="login-page">
      <div class="form">
          <p>Admin Login</p>
        <form class="login-form">
          <input id="ie"type="text" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input id="ip"type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
          <button id="loginbtn" onclick="login()">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
             <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.0/firebase.js"></script>
            <script>
            // Initialize Firebase 
                 var config = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyA8QeKSDbtgq6GiSS3MBjU2i43IZgYeMRE",
                authDomain: "web-app-login-a90bb.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://web-app-login-a90bb.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "web-app-login-a90bb",
                storageBucket: "web-app-login-a90bb.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "695872421055"
                };

            firebase.initializeApp(config);

            </script>
            <script src="index.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

---